# Collection of interface from single object

Tags: java, generics, collections, casting

I have class `SampleClass` implementing interface `ISampleInterface`.
Method is requiring `Collection<ISampleInterface>` as argument, but in my code I want to pass single `SampleClass` object.
I was trying to make some casting:

```
Collection<ISampleInterface> col = 
   (Collection<ISampleInterface>) Arrays.asList(new SampleClass[]{sampleClassInstance});
```

But I got casting error:

```
Cannot cast from List<SampleClass> to Collection<ISampleInterface>
```

Any ideas how to do it in one elegant line?

Comment: Can't you just do `Arrays.asList(new ISampleClass[]{sampleClassInstance})`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try creating the right type of array in `asList()` call:

```
Collection<ISampleInterface> col = 
   (Collection<ISampleInterface>) Arrays.asList(
       new ISampleInterface[] { sampleClassInstance });
```

Then again, the 'elegance' ship has sailed IMO...

I also don't think you need to explicitly cast to `(Collection<ISampleInterface>)`. So your could should become

```
Collection<ISampleInterface> col = Arrays.asList(
   new ISampleInterface[] { sampleClassInstance });
```

which is a bit more elegant right there

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16319064/697449) for slightly more elegance.

Comment: Yup, you're right. I'm using Guava most of the time, wasn't aware of Collections.singleton() API, good to know!

Comment: Yeah `ImmutableSet.of(sampleClassInstance)` is pretty much synonymous. I know some Guava users like to just use the immutable implementations instead of `Collections`' empty/singleton implementations for consistency.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to specify the right generic type argument:

```
Collection<ISampleInterface> col =
        Arrays.<ISampleInterface>asList(sampleClassInstance);
```

Notice that `new SampleClass[] { ... }` is unnecessary because `asList` takes `T...` ([varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html)) so the array creation is implicit.

More to the point, you could write:

```
Collection<ISampleInterface> col =
        Collections.<ISampleInterface>singleton(sampleClassInstance);
```

From the [`Collections.singleton`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singleton%28T%29) javadoc:

> Returns an immutable set containing only the specified object. The returned set is serializable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the signature to use `Collection<? extends ISampleInterface>`

Answer (score -1):

The reason for the error is that generics in java are not type covariant. You can read tutorials on web in this regard.

You can use following alternative:

```
col.addAll(Arrays.asList(new SampleClass[]{sampleClassInstance}));
```